# Change the color of the line based on the value of y-axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, apexcharts, recharts

Good day to you all, I'm having a problem with changing the colour of the graph line on the base of the value of the y-axis. I want to set a limit to Y-axis. For example, if the value of the Y-axis point is between 40 to 60 in the case of the max y-axis being 100, I want the colour of the line to be red else blue.

```
if (y-axis is between 40 to 60) {
  the colour of the line should be red on that points
}
else {
  on other points it should be blue
}
```

Codepen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-playground-forked-tc0xf?file=/index.js

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem